# How to insert data into SQL Server from both Flutter and ASP.NET at the same time then show data in control panel using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flutter, api, rest, asp.net-core

How to insert data into SQL Server from both Flutter and ASP.NET at the same time then show data in control panel using asp.net

How to insert data into SQL Server from both Flutter and ASP.NET at the same time then show data in control panel using asp.net .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Real Time Notifications using SignalR and SQL Dependency.

When the data changed in sql server, it will notifies us.

**Related Links**

[1. Asp.Net Application Turotial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/883702/Real-Time-Notifications-using-SignalR-and-SQL-Depe)

[2. Implementing SignalR in ASP.NET Core Web App (MVC) for real-time database updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159844/implementing-signalr-in-asp-net-core-web-app-(mvc))